# VBA WORD Labels at start at end of selection

Tags: vba, ms-word, selection, label

I'm trying to select text and add some labels at the start/end, and do some stuff in each paragraph of the selection, but I don't know why happens this::

```
Sub TESTBotones()
    Dim p As Paragraph, i As Integer, total As Integer, r As Range
    Set r = Selection.Range
    total = Selection.Paragraphs.Count
    For i = 1 To total
        Set p = r.Paragraphs(i)
        p.Range.Text = "***" & p.Range.Text
    Next
    r.Text = "((BOTONES))" & Chr(13) & r.Text & Chr(13) & "((/BOTONES))" & Chr(13)
    Debug.Print r.Paragraphs.Count

End Sub
```

As you can see if you exe this macro, in the Debug.print line, the number of paragraphs decrease in 1 after exiting For Loop...WHY??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this working fine :)

```
Sub TESTBotones()
    Dim p As Paragraph, i As Integer, total As Integer, r As Range
    Set r = Selection.Range
    total = Selection.Paragraphs.Count
    For i = 1 To total
        Set p = r.Paragraphs(i)
        p.Range.InsertBefore "***"
    Next
    r.InsertBefore "((BOTONES))" & Chr(13)
    r.InsertAfter Chr(13) & "((/BOTONES))" & Chr(13)
    Debug.Print r.Paragraphs.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: Late, but still counting 1 less :S

Comment: i you have selected 3 paragraphs this will count 5 because 2 paragraphs we are adding... 1 before and 1 after the selection

Comment: Then why the hell my version count 1 less at the moment it leaves the For loop???

Comment: Just Add [r.Select] after [p.Range.Text = "***" & p.Range.Text] line in for loop, and debug this code line by line and see in ur selected range you will know whats going on...

Comment: Well, when it exits from the loop, Selections.paragraphs.count decreases in 1 xDDD. I'm saving start and end

Comment: Could you please upvote this? I need to ask a question about controlling overwritting in SaveAs Method, but I've searched and found nothing. I don't know why people downvote most of my question :S. Or if you don't want to upvote, please ask it for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: there you go.... be happy dude... ok now, did you get **selection** issue answer?

Comment: Thanks dude. I didn't found why it decreases counter on exit, but I'm saving Start and end of selection in 2 vars, so I'm happy for now.

Comment: BTW I think you should upvote the Questions instead of the answer, The message I'm getting is "
You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."
Stack's Machine seems to think my questions are useless(because of some downvotings I can't understand at all)

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved with this:

```
Sub Pestañas()
    Dim p As Paragraph, i As Integer, j As Integer, total As Integer, r As Range, ini As Long, fin As Long, menos As Integer
    Set r = Selection.Range
    ini = Selection.Start
    fin = Selection.End
    If ini = fin Then Exit Sub
    For i = 1 To total
       Set p = r.Paragraphs(i)
       p.Range.Text = "***" & p.Range.Text
    Next
    r.SetRange Start:=ini, End:=fin
    r.Text = "((THING))" & Chr(13) & r.Text & "((OTHER THING))" & Chr(13)



End Sub
```